# Typo3: Reference about TSFE array

Tags: typo3

Where can be found references about the $GLOBALS['TSFE'] variable for typo3?

For example some code snippets report that "TSFE:id" is the id of the current page, but where can I find the reference about this variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There used to be a (incomplete) section on TYPO3's wiki, but it seems to be gone now. You can find it on the wayback machine though:
https://web.archive.org/web/20130621221807/http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/getText

The only online "documentation" that I know of is the TYPO3 source of the TypoScript Frontend Controller (a.k.a. TSFE):
https://api.typo3.org/TYPO3_8-7/_typo_script_frontend_controller_8php_source.html

It's all of the public properties you can access directly via TS:

```
10 = TEXT
10.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|username
```

Comment: The Wiki page (first link) is a page about the TypoScript TSFE. For this, there actually is a documentation page (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/Data.html?highlight=tsfe#tsfe), though it is a bit sparse.

Comment: There is also a (new) dedicated TSFE page in Typo3 Explained (since v10): https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/TSFE/Index.html

Answer (score 4):

There is none. Really :-(.

But you also must know that $GLOBALS['TSFE'] (TypoScript Frontend) is not just an array containing some information, TSFE also consists of objects that can be used by extensions or in TypoScript context to access data from the current page or user. E.g.

$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page is an instance of \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user is an instance of \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Authentication\FrontendUserAuthentication

So basically the documentation is spread all over the TYPO3 documentation. You will also realize that a lot of the information can be accessed or used by TypoScript or TYPO3 API without needing to parse the TSFE array.

Comment: `$GLOBALS['TSFE']` is not an array. If, initialized, it is an instantiated object of the class `TypoScriptFrontendController` (hence the name) or the fully qualified: `\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController`. Please see TSFE page in the official documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/TSFE/Index.html Also, in this case, the source code of TypoScriptFrontendController is the most authoritative "documenation".

Answer (score 0):

For **newer** TYPO3 versions (since TYPO3 **version 10**), there is now a [dedicated TSFE page](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/TSFE/Index.html) in "TYPO3 Explained":

- [TSFE in **PHP**](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/TSFE/Index.html)
- [TSFE in **TypoScript**](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/Data.html?highlight=tsfe#tsfe)
- TSFE.config in **Page TSconfig** (was deprecated in version 9 and removed in 10, so I won't link to it)

**Important:** Many properties of TSFE (TypoScriptFrontendController) are now no longer public or are marked as `@internal`. If marked as `@internal`, the property, method or class can be made private or dropped without a deprecation or further notice.

The page [TSFE](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/TSFE/Index.html) in "TYPO3 Explained" contains some examples and alternatives which are now used to get the current page id, language information, the base URL etc.

Example for retrieving current page id (in the frontend):

```
$pageArguments = $request->getAttribute('routing');
$pageId = $pageArguments->getPageId();
```

If you still need to use TSFE (in PHP) it is recommended to use the `frontend.controller` request attribute (since v11) and no longer use `$GLOBALS['TSFE']` directly:

```
$frontendController = $request->getAttribute('frontend.controller'));
```

---

This also concerns **TypoScript**: There are deprecated since v12:

- baseUrl, use site configuration, see changelog "[Deprecation: #99170 - config.baseURL and  tag functionality](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.1/Deprecation-99170-ConfigbaseURLAndBaseTagFunctionality.html)" (v12)

These are also deprecated since v12:

- spamProtectEmailAddresses
- intTarget
- extTarget
- fileTarget

You can access the TypoScript properties directly like

```
lib.something.data = TSFE:config|config|fileTarget
```

---

It is strongly advised to look in the documentation and the [changelogs](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Index.html) and make yourself familiar with the changes.